# tagging words with # and @replies when submitting a form!! twitter style?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, twitter

can you someone help or direct me to a good tutorial, on how to detect @replies and #tags when submitting a form like twitter? and also when retrieving the information from mysql and displaying them using php, they become links instaed of just plain texts. so basically it detects it and then makes it linkable!! i hope this makes sense!! thanks

Comment: Simple text processing. Do you really need a tutorial for that?

Comment: sorry im a bit of a newbie!! is thier any toturials!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://github.com/mikenz/twitter-text-php  i found the php version for the twitter text processing, they only had it in ruby on rails, but someone did a php library for it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has released libraries that do just that!

http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html